# How to: Set Up an ODBC Data Source automatically from a script

Tags: sql-server, odbc

How to Set Up an ODBC Data Source using a script in ms-sql ? or other script ?
i need to do this automatically without the need to go to control panel and choose to add a data source and choose driver etc..
Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to configure DSN  via `odbcad32.exe` or via registry editing, you can use connect string that points to MS SQL driver, server and database. This looks like:

```
Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=127.0.0.1;Database=test;Uid=mn;Pwd=****;
```

For more examples look at: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/ in ODBC section